# incorrect response object returned using restygwt

Tags: java, json, rest, servlets, gwt

I'm making client-server application with restygwt. I have written my methods and made a servlet.

```
    @GET
    @Path("/get/getpoints/{projectId}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    void getAZPoints(@PathParam("projectId") BigInteger projectID,
        MethodCallback <Map<String, String>> responseWithName);
```

I get incorrect response from server on client side when using response of `Map<String, String>` type. Servlet return data like this:

```
["1":"New Pole","2":"New Manhole","3":"New Container 2","4":"New Building#11"]
```

but there when it recieved, my response contains only 2 entries.

Though if I change type to `List<String>`

```
    @GET
    @Path("/get/getpoints/{projectId}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    void getAZPoints(@PathParam("projectId") BigInteger projectID,
        MethodCallback <List<String>> responseWithName);
```

my response is the same as servlet return data.

Can you help me solving this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that it is a well known problem - https://github.com/resty-gwt/resty-gwt/issues/119. It occures because my string (that is actually a number string in my example like "123" and so on) is sent like a number and got decode in a wrong way. As a solution, I send my big integer as a string with some text charecters and decode it on a client side. Now it works fine.